# How to extract a specific value from array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi here i am having an array,

```
   const JSON_PAGES = ['my-needs','a-bit-about-me','my-home','my-income']
```

and an object like this

```
const columnsFromBackend = {
  "my-needs": {
    name: "my-needs",
    items: [{ name: "Dhanush", age: 24 }]
  },
  "a-bit-about-me": {
    name: "a-bit-about-me",
    items: [{ name: "Dharma", age: 24 }]
  },
  "my-home": {
    name: "my-home",
    items: [{ name: "Sachin", age: 24 }]
  },
  "my-income": {
    name: "my-income",
    items: [{ name: "Kumar", age: 24 }]
  }
};
```

In the above array i.e **JSON_PAGES** whose values are present as a key inside the above mentioned object i.e  **columnsFromBackend**.

i need to extract the **items** value from the object by using the **JSON_PAGES** array values. Like this

**result:**

```
let myneeds = [{ name: "Dhanush", age: 24 }];
let abitaboutme = [{ name: "Dharma", age: 24 }]
let myhome = [{ name: "Sachin", age: 24 }]
let myincome = [{ name: "Kumar", age: 24 }]
```

For referencing i have added the extracted values in a variable. Is there any way i can compare the array with the object and get the required value. Please help me with that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need the results in separate variables?

Comment: just extracting values also ok

Comment: The variable names are not valid. A variable may not contain the `-` character.

Comment: thanks..i have edited

Comment: Still not a valid name `abitabout-me`

Comment: I'm not sure how you would generate variables dynamically? what's the goal? why not just an array with the values?

Comment: yeah an array with the values are okay

Comment: Have you tried even once to work on this and make some effort yourself? What issues did you face and where are you stuck?

Comment: Why do you need to extract the values into variables? Can't you use the `columnsFromBackend` directly? For example `columnsFromBackend["my-needs"].items`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let values = JSON_PAGES.map((page) => columnsFromBackend[page].items)
let [my_need,abitaboutme,myhome,myincome] = values;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the results into an array, 
You can get the values to look for by using `Object.values(columnsFromBackend)`, then `filter()` the items and finally use `map()` on the result to return an array with the output you want.

```js
const JSON_PAGES = ['my-needs','a-bit-about-me','my-home','my-income']

const columnsFromBackend = {
  "my-needs": {
    name: "my-needs",
    items: [{ name: "Dhanush", age: 24 }]
  },
  "a-bit-about-me": {
    name: "a-bit-about-me",
    items: [{ name: "Dharma", age: 24 }]
  },
  "my-home": {
    name: "my-home",
    items: [{ name: "Sachin", age: 24 }]
  },
  "my-income": {
    name: "my-income",
    items: [{ name: "Kumar", age: 24 }]
  }
};

const res = Object.values(columnsFromBackend).filter(item => JSON_PAGES.includes(item.name)).map(({ items }) => items);

console.log(res)
```